# VS2010, Windows Form Application

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010

As part of the application, I am trying to update an excel sheet using ado. But I get an error stating "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties".

Code is as below. Can anyone please suggest . Thanks.

```
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rc As New ADODB.Recordset NewNmae = "INSERT INTO [Names$]  VALUES('ASDASD','ASDASDASD','ASDASDASD');"
    cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
     "DBQ=" & ListNames

    cn.Open(cn.ConnectionString)

    rc.Open(NewNmae, cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)


    cn.Close()
    rc.Close()`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the provider to Jet OLEDB:

cn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";

Comment: Tried that. I now get an error 'External Table Not in Expected Format'

Comment: Can you try another connection string:ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\MyFolder\MyWorkbook.xls;" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Comment: Tried that as well.A new error. "Data Source name too long"